# Remove mirror copies of sub-arrays in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Consider an array of 30K (or more) sub-arrays, something like this:

```
[[A,B],[C,D],[E,F],[G,H]......[D,C],[H,G]]
```

- Sub-arrays ALWAYS contain only 2 elements.
- SOME sub-arrays have their mirror image somewhere in the array.

What is the *fastest* way to **remove all mirrored sub-arrays from the main array**? As in: in the above example, say, remove `[D,C]` OR `[C,D]` but **NOT** both?

What I have tried:

- `.splice()` with a backwards `for` loop.
- `forEach` loop.
- `.stringify()` and `.join()`.
- `if (array.indexOf([array[i][1], array[i][0]) > -1)`
- `if (array.indexOf(array[i].reverse()) > -1)`

Nothing seems to be working and in `forEach` loop case combined with string comparison freezes the browser.

A simple code to first see if it works at all:

```
for (var i=0; i < l; i++) {
    if (arr.indexOf([arr[i][1],arr[i][0]]) > -1) console.log(arr[i])
}
```

most other things that I tried are variations of the above code but every time the entire array gets logged to the console.

UPDATE:
sub-arrays are basically just English words, more specifically synonym pairs.
so `["always","forever"]` exists and so does `[forever, always]`. this isn't the case for every pair/word but there are many such cases throughout the array. I want to loop through the entire array and remove any 1 array of such "pairs". which one is removed doesn't matter. in the end, the resulting array should have no "mirror" arrays. I hope this better clarifies what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: *"Nothing seems to be working"*: please provide the code that doesn't work. Asking for the *fastest* way, is better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but then you must present working code. So maybe focus on one question: "I tried this [code] and it produced [this output] for this [input], while I expect [this output]. What is wrong with my code?".

Comment: Can you provide sample input, and expected output? What is the data type of the elements of the pairs? If they are not primitives, when do you consider them to be equal? When mirrors occur, which of them do you want to keep? ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `indexOf` with an array literal as argument is always going to return -1. That array literal is a new array, and so that reference will not be present in your array. Objects (arrays) are equal when they reference the *same* memory location.

As a solution you could sort each pair, and then map that pair to JSON. This array of JSON strings can then be fed to a `Map`, so that the JSON will serve as unique key. The corresponding value can be the original pair.

This solution will retain the *last* occurrence of mirrors/duplicates:

```js
let arr = [["a", "b"], ["f", "c"], ["m", "q"], ["b", "a"], ["q", "s"], ["c", "f"], ["b", "z"]];

let map = new Map(arr.map(pair => [JSON.stringify([...pair].sort()), pair]));
let result = [...map.values()];

console.log(result);
```

If you don't mind that the original array is mutated, then you can replace `[...pair]` with just `pair`. The result will then also have its pairs sorted.

Comment: thanks! it worked perfectly and it was blazing fast.